# Get cart items details by user id in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, session, woocommerce, cart

I'm trying to display the cart details of all registered users on the backend.

Answer (score 8):

To get cart items details by user ID *(for example for backend usage)* is from WooCommerce sessions like in this working example *(for a defined user ID)*:

```
// The User ID
$user_id = 123;

// Get an instance of the WC_Session_Handler Object
$session_handler = new WC_Session_Handler();

// Get the user session from its user ID:
$session = $session_handler->get_session($user_id);

// Get cart items array
$cart_items = maybe_unserialize($session['cart']);

// Loop through cart items and get cart items details
foreach( $cart_items as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
    $product_id   = $cart_item['product_id'];
    $variation_id = $cart_item['variation_id'];
    $quantity     = $cart_item['quantity'];
    $attributes   = $cart_item['variation'];
    $item_taxes   = $cart_item['line_tax_data'];
    $subtotal_tax = $cart_item['line_subtotal_tax'];
    $total_tax    = $cart_item['line_tax'];
    $subtotal     = $cart_item['line_subtotal'];
    $total        = $cart_item['line_total'];
}
```